# React Native navigating between screens, screen size shrinking bug

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Please see the attached image.

[image]

Essentials: When I navigate to a new scene, the previous screen looks to be shrinking or moving upward, this isn't the typical UX pattern on Apple apps - any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct, that is not the default iOS navigation transition, it is a custom navigation transition that the React Native team created that they use on their own apps.

If you're using the `Navigator` component, you can see how they customize their scene transition configuration [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/21fda19ca9bc15eae8781b0095673d0be70d9ff7/Libraries/CustomComponents/Navigator/NavigatorSceneConfigs.js). Notice how on some scene configurations they change the `scale` during transition (search for `scale` in that file). If you don't want this to happen, you can customize it using the [`configureScene` prop](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html#configurescene), otherwise you will have to set a background color to the `Navigator` itself to not notice the page shrinking, for example, `<Navigator style={{ backgroundColor: '#your-bg-color' }} {...otherProps} />`, but I doubt you will want to do this.

If you're using `NavigationExperimental`, [they do the same thing](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/38a6eec0db85a5204e85a9a92b4dee2db9641671/Libraries/CustomComponents/NavigationExperimental/NavigationCardStackStyleInterpolator.js) if you use the `NavigationCardStack`. Unfortunately, they don't really let you customize the transition animation on `NavigationCardStack` except for the `direction`. In order to be able to customize your navigation transitions in `NavigationExperimental`, you need to use [`NavigationTransitioner`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/85a6f011b6e4d9f86bc82437c88273f4cc2782d3/Libraries/NavigationExperimental/NavigationTransitioner.js).

Comment: Great response, thanks for the reply! I'm actually using react-flux-router at the moment - From what I can tell they only support the 'fade' transition and directional movement at the moment, which is a shame - would you recommend anything else which might offer a more iOS native feel?

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/879) to fix this issue.

Basically you can write a custom interpolation function to overwrite the behaviour of NavigationCardStack and apply that to the scene. However this only applies to forward transitions, to backwards it still keeps the scaling for me. You have to experience with that.